# Is it possible to toss data to another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I  just Make timer that can use in life. just like image that I push in here, if I go back to main ViewController then I wanna the number that I input in set view controller are tossed to viewController so when I go back to main ViewController and press restart then that number gonna be in text of CountTimeLabel.. but I really don't know how to toss data that I input in another view controller to root viewController... pleas help me.. if I write code like ViewController().variableName = 30 in setViewController, that dose not make things well..(I already know about prepare function but that is not what I am finding..because this is happen when I go back to ViewController(RootViewController)) I will put my code in below..
is it possible to toss data to another view controller from other view controller?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet var AllTileLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var SumTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var CountTimeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var StartButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var StopButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var ResetButton: UIButton!

var timeTrigger = true
var realTime = Timer()
var second : Int = 3000
var sum : Int = 14400
var allTime : Int = 14400
var IntSecond : Int = 0
var ifReset = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    StartButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    StopButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    ResetButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func StartButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if timeTrigger { checkTimeTrigger() }
    print("Start")
}

@IBAction func StopButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    endGame()
}
@IBAction func ResetButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(second)
    getTimeData()
    //second = 3000
    //CountTimeLabel.text = "0:50:00"
    CountTimeLabel.text = printTime(temp: second)
    ifReset = true
}
@IBAction func Reset(_ sender: UIButton) {
    endGame()
    timeTrigger = true
    realTime = Timer()
    second = 3000
    sum = 14400
    allTime = 14400
    IntSecond = 0
    ifReset = false

    AllTileLabel.text = "8:00:00"
    SumTimeLabel.text = "0:0:0"
    CountTimeLabel.text = "0:50:00"
}

@objc func updateCounter(){
//        if String(format: "%.2f",second) == "0.00"{
        if second < 1 {
            endGame()
            CountTimeLabel.text = "종료"
        } else {
            second = second - 1
            sum = sum + 1
            allTime = allTime - 1
            AllTileLabel.text = printTime(temp: allTime)
            SumTimeLabel.text = printTime(temp: sum)
            CountTimeLabel.text = printTime(temp: second)
            print("update")
        }
    }

func checkTimeTrigger() {
    realTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timeTrigger = false
}

func endGame() {
    realTime.invalidate()
    timeTrigger = true
}

func printTime(temp : Int) -> String
{
    let S = temp%60
    let H = temp/3600
    let M = temp/60 - H*60

    let returnString = String(H) + ":" + String(M) + ":" + String(S)
    return returnString
}

func getTimeData() {
    second = 20
    sum = SetViewController().real.sum
    allTime = SetViewController().real.allTime
    print(second)
}

}











import UIKit

class SetViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var View1: UIView!
@IBOutlet var View2: UIView!
@IBOutlet var InputView1: UIView!
@IBOutlet var InputView2: UIView!
@IBOutlet var SetButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var H1TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var M1TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var H2TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var M2TextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    H1TextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    M1TextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    H2TextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    M2TextField.keyboardType = .numberPad

    View1.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    View2.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    InputView1.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    InputView2.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    SetButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func SetButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEmrM.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Welcome new user!  It's a tricky question, everyone has opinions on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a hobbyist programmer and you just want to "get it done", simply use a static.

Let's say `Bottom: UIViewController` is the "main", root, view controller at the absolute "base" of your app.  no matter what happens "Bottom" is always there.

Say `Timer: UIViewController` is (any) other view controller you put on top for some reason.

In Bottom, do this

```
class Bottom: UIViewController, etc ... {
    
    static weak var current: Bottom? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Bottom.current = self
    }
    
    func testing() {
        print("it works, WTH")
    }
```

Note that in ViewDidLoad, you simply set it.

Next, say you are in `Timer`, try this:

```
class Timer: UIViewController, etc ... {
    
    func someFunction() {
        Bottom.current.testing()  // it's that easy
    }
```

It's that easy.

---

Note there is a ***huge amount of confusion*** about using statics, singletons, and similar approaches in iPhone programming.

(Just for example, many engineers will say "avoid singletons!"  This is remarkably confused because in iOS engineering, almost everything *is* a singleton (notably *the app itself* (!!!!!), the screen, the GPS, etc etc.)

In any event, as a beginner hobbyist, learn how to use statics (it's simple .. `Bottom.current. ...` as above), and eventually you can learn about the pros and cons of such things.